# Cannot inject form control in Angular5 directive (NullInjectorError: No provider for FormControl!)

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to pass in my from control attached to an input to my directive but i am getting the following error 'NullInjectorError: No provider for FormControl!'.

Basically i am trying to create a validator that watches another input and makes sure the value on our input is always less or equal.

I know there are other ways to do it but i would like to implement this as a validator and inject the formcontrol on the validated field in the input. I have included the component, directive and modules code if that helps and also a stackblitz link to the example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-zxb1t2

component html code:

```
<div>
<input 
required
placeholder="total"
[formControl]="total">

<div *ngIf="total.invalid">{{getErrors(total)}}</div>

<input
required 
[lessThanInput]="total"
placeholder="less than total" 
[formControl]="lessThanTotal">

<div *ngIf="lessThanTotal.invalid">{{getErrors(lessThanTotal}}</div>
```

directive code:

```
 import { FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, ValidatorFn} from 

    "@angular/forms";
    import {
      AfterContentInit,
      Directive, ElementRef,
      Input,
    } from "@angular/core";

    @Directive({
      selector: '[lessThanInput]',
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: LessThanOtherControl,
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    })
    export class LessThanOtherControl implements Validator {
      validator: ValidatorFn;
      @Input() lessThanInput:FormControl;
      @Input() otherControlName: string;
      subscription: any;

      //if i remove fc:Formcontrol the error goes away but i cannot then access the form control through the constructor. Is this even possible? iIthought it was.
      constructor(private el: ElementRef, private fc: FormControl) {
        console.log(fc);
        this.validator = this.validateLessThanOther;
        this.lessThanInput.valueChanges.subscribe(this.fc.updateValueAndValidity);
      }

      validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
      }

      validateLessThanOther(control: FormControl) {

        if (control && control.value) {
          if (isNaN(+control.value) || isNaN(+this.lessThanInput.value)) {
            return null;
          }

          const isValid = +control.value <= +this.lessThanInput.value;

          return isValid ? null : {
            'biggerThanOtherField': {
              value: control.value,
              otherInputName: this.otherControlName
            }
          };
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

module code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LessThanOtherControl,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: []
})
```

Comment: You say you have a *stackblitz link to the example*. Where is that?

Comment: @R.Richards Oops forgot that important bit, your help would be appreciated, thank you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-zxb1t2

Comment: Just a quick note, because I have to run out in a minute. Think about making the `fc: FormControl` another `@Input`, like you have with the other one (`lessThanInput`). Typically, only services are injected via the ctor. And, you cannot *provide* a `FormControl` as a service

Comment: @R.Richards I was trying to avoid that thank you, i shall keep on searching. I am not sure how the current directives inject the FormControl in template driven validation so i will have a look at the angular core to see if any answers lay there.If anyone else has any answers that would be helpful.